# does glVertexAttribDivisor affect non-instanced glDrawArrays calls?

Tags: opengl

Do setting vertex attribute divisors with `glVertexAttribDivisor` affect non-instanced draw calls EG `glDrawArrays`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glDrawArrays` or `DrawArraysOneInstance` (from the core spec) will draw one instance for all the primitives it draws. This means that the `gl_instance_id` will remain 0 for the whole draw call. Instanced attributes will only have their first instance accessed for all primitives. (although it is possible to provide a base offset to gl_instance_id)

**For Example:** a call to `glDrawArrays` to draw 6 triangle primitives, will only use the first instance of any instanced attributes for every primitive that it draws.

**It's not possible to have attributes that advance per primitive.**

For more details, see section 10.4 of the opengl4.6 [core spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

All "non-instanced" draw calls are instanced draw calls. They merely draw one instance, starting with a base instance of 0. So instanced attributes still act like instanced attributes.

Comment: Do you mean that one call to glDrawArrays will draw one instance no matter how many primitives it draws? Or does it draw as many instances as there are of the primitive type?

Comment: I ended up answering this question in my answer to this question